# Notification message not shown when application in open state for Azure push notification service in Xamarin iOS App

Tags: azure, push-notification, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

I am developing Xamarin forms application, I have enabled the Push notification process for sending the updates for my app to the users in Xamarin iOS platform. I have used the Azure Notification Hub service to integrate the sending of messages to the installed users of my application. I have followed procedure mentioned in below link for both development and production,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/push-notifications/azure/

I have sent notification message through test send process. Notification shown properly when application in minimized or closed or unlocked state. When application is in open state, didn't received any Notification message and alert window only shown in it. For my scenario no need to show alert window, instead of that navigate to another page in it.

```
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
        {
            var pushSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes (
                       UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound,
                       new NSSet ()); 
UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(pushSettings);
               UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
                return true;
        }

public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
        {
            NSDictionary aps = userInfo.ObjectForKey(new NSString("aps")) as NSDictionary; 

            App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new SamplePage());
        }
```

Do we acheive this or is this behaviour of Azure push notification process.

Comment: What do you mean "alert window only shown in it"? You can try to clear the app's badge.

Comment: Hi @LandLu-MSFT, I have edited in above query and also added initial registration query. Did you mean to clear badge included in `UIUserNotificationType`.
I mean alert window as below code mentioned in ReceivedRemoteNotification() process.
`UIAlertView avAlert = new UIAlertView("Notification", alert, null, "OK", null);
                    avAlert.Show();`
I have referred this in below link,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started